# HERE Geocoder Autocomplete API missing places

Tags: geocoding, here-api, reverse-geocoding

I'm currently adding HERE Geocoder autocomplete to an iOS app.

But I see some places that can't be found such as Santorini, Greece.
The result for

```
https://autocomplete.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?&query=Santorin&maxresults=20&language=en
```

Only returns street addresses and not Santorini island although wego.here.com finds it.

```
{"suggestions":[{"label":"Netherlands, 1045, Amsterdam, Santoriniweg","language":"en","countryCode":"NLD","locationId":"NT_ODFR4did5xjj5uJK4btqlA","address":{"country":"Netherlands","state":"North Holland","county":"Amsterdam","city":"Amsterdam","district":"Westpoort","street":"Santoriniweg","postalCode":"1045"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Netherlands, 1045 AV, Amsterdam, Santoriniweg","language":"en","countryCode":"NLD","locationId":"NT_Smor9u.as.-MmJqJq4vpAB","address":{"country":"Netherlands","state":"North Holland","county":"Amsterdam","city":"Amsterdam","district":"Westpoort","street":"Santoriniweg","postalCode":"1045 AV"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Greece, 166 72, Vari, Santorinis","language":"en","countryCode":"GRC","locationId":"NT_IaIOJq9v7WYxvwyBNTAKqD","address":{"country":"Greece","state":"Attiki","county":"Attiki","city":"Vari","district":"Vari","street":"Santorinis","postalCode":"166 72"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Greece, 194 00, Kropia, Santorinis","language":"en","countryCode":"GRC","locationId":"NT_.v2MllUnnhl9celWvRKH4C","address":{"country":"Greece","state":"Attiki","county":"Attiki","city":"Kropia","street":"Santorinis","postalCode":"194 00"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Greece, 131 22, Ilion, Santorinis","language":"en","countryCode":"GRC","locationId":"NT_yPPQvWgiBNlGVGTkT6eIuC","address":{"country":"Greece","state":"Attiki","county":"Attiki","city":"Ilion","district":"Ilion","street":"Santorinis","postalCode":"131 22"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Greece, 163 46, Ilioupoli, Santorinis","language":"en","countryCode":"GRC","locationId":"NT_jrZ4MlUZv9lGdahlvr1hzD","address":{"country":"Greece","state":"Attiki","county":"Attiki","city":"Ilioupoli","district":"Ilioupoli","street":"Santorinis","postalCode":"163 46"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"United States, WV, 26508, Morgantown, Santorini Ave","language":"en","countryCode":"USA","locationId":"NT_mlRzl5iPlnZJVdkC43qBxA","address":{"country":"United States","state":"WV","county":"Monongalia","city":"Morgantown","street":"Santorini Ave","postalCode":"26508"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Greece, 264 42, Patra, Santorinis","language":"en","countryCode":"GRC","locationId":"NT_3Bnweqsd2M6s94-l-GBgNB","address":{"country":"Greece","state":"Dytiki Ellada","county":"Achaia","city":"Patra","district":"Patra","street":"Santorinis","postalCode":"264 42"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Greece, 141 21, Irakleio, Santorinis","language":"en","countryCode":"GRC","locationId":"NT_C-O.wA8liN2ACYEL--mxLA","address":{"country":"Greece","state":"Attiki","county":"Attiki","city":"Irakleio","district":"Irakleio","street":"Santorinis","postalCode":"141 21"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Netherlands, 3059, Rotterdam, Santorinihof","language":"en","countryCode":"NLD","locationId":"NT_0gHl3.zNTvAjT-DCVHfZ9B","address":{"country":"Netherlands","state":"South Holland","county":"Rotterdam","city":"Rotterdam","district":"Prins Alexander","street":"Santorinihof","postalCode":"3059"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Greece, 173 43, Agios Dimitrios, Santorinis","language":"en","countryCode":"GRC","locationId":"NT_bleQqboZkA2kcRVaQPILvA","address":{"country":"Greece","state":"Attiki","county":"Attiki","city":"Agios Dimitrios","district":"Agios Dimitrios","street":"Santorinis","postalCode":"173 43"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"United States, CA, 94550, Livermore, Santorino Dr","language":"en","countryCode":"USA","locationId":"NT_lnCUezFO4W2rEKEyep7nPC","address":{"country":"United States","state":"CA","county":"Alameda","city":"Livermore","street":"Santorino Dr","postalCode":"94550"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"United States, CA, 95037, Morgan Hill, Santorini Ln","language":"en","countryCode":"USA","locationId":"NT_fsBi476iNcXtp3XrgY2LxA","address":{"country":"United States","state":"CA","county":"Santa Clara","city":"Morgan Hill","street":"Santorini Ln","postalCode":"95037"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Greece, 715 00, Gazi, Santorinis","language":"en","countryCode":"GRC","locationId":"NT_A7.PUnw0BeLzi67flvpm6C","address":{"country":"Greece","state":"Crete","county":"Heraklion","city":"Gazi","street":"Santorinis","postalCode":"715 00"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Greece, 193 00, Aspropyrgos, Santorinis","language":"en","countryCode":"GRC","locationId":"NT_l3QtynJdwyaiPpJQy9kzFC","address":{"country":"Greece","state":"Attiki","county":"Attiki","city":"Aspropyrgos","street":"Santorinis","postalCode":"193 00"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"United States, OH, 43054, New Albany, Santorini Dr","language":"en","countryCode":"USA","locationId":"NT_XnOvF3rsaPW6SDHLVtgRKD","address":{"country":"United States","state":"OH","county":"Franklin","city":"New Albany","district":"Central College","street":"Santorini Dr","postalCode":"43054"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Greece, 415 00, Larisa, Santorinis","language":"en","countryCode":"GRC","locationId":"NT_4rpfnGV.QHCmyeyEc.OZ3C","address":{"country":"Greece","state":"Thessalia","county":"Larisa","city":"Larisa","district":"Larisa","street":"Santorinis","postalCode":"415 00"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"Netherlands, 2134 AR, Hoofddorp, Santorini","language":"en","countryCode":"NLD","locationId":"NT_btO6NsAaTwMqDTbpIypRmD","address":{"country":"Netherlands","state":"North Holland","county":"Haarlemmermeer","city":"Hoofddorp","street":"Santorini","postalCode":"2134 AR"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"United States, CA, 90630, Cypress, Santorini Dr","language":"en","countryCode":"USA","locationId":"NT_hhdqA4OCqrLwjit3SQ4mCA","address":{"country":"United States","state":"CA","county":"Orange","city":"Cypress","street":"Santorini Dr","postalCode":"90630"},"matchLevel":"street"},{"label":"United States, FL, 34119, Naples, Santorini Ct","language":"en","countryCode":"USA","locationId":"NT_IFfgAvpSW08aOoesZwU0QA","address":{"country":"United States","state":"FL","county":"Collier","city":"Naples","district":"Olde Cypress","street":"Santorini Ct","postalCode":"34119"},"matchLevel":"street"}]}
```

Is it possible to filter the type of results to remove street ?

Answer (score 0):

A Search with the Geocoder will not return Islands. Geocoding is about Addresses (and some landmarks) only.

The Landmark Geocoding will find some landmarks like parks, airports or tourist attractions. See https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-search.html for more details.

If you rather want to find Islands and businesses and other POIs, consider evaluating the Places API (https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/quick-start-find-text-string.html)